# If $\frac{(a-b)(c-d)}{(b-c)(d-a)} = \frac{2016}{2017}$ , find $\frac{(a-c)(b-d)}{(a-b)(c-d)}$ .

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

> If $\frac{(a-b)(c-d)}{(b-c)(d-a)} = \frac{2016}{2017}$ , find $\frac{(a-c)(b-d)}{(a-b)(c-d)}$ .

**What I Tried** :- First I thought for a moment and found out that I can write this :
$$\frac{(a-c)(b-d)}{(b-c)(d-a)} = \frac{(a-c)(b-d)}{(a-b)(c-d)} * \frac{2016}{2017}$$

But how is it going to help?

Then I thought maybe cross-multiply everything and try to factor it? I get :-
$$2017(a-b)(c-d) = 2016(b-c)(d-a)$$
$$\rightarrow 2017(a-b)(c-d) - 2016(b-c)(d-a) = 0$$
$$\rightarrow 2017(ac - ad - bc + bd) - 2016(bd - ab - cd - ac) = 0$$
$$\rightarrow 2017ac + bd + 2016ab + 2016cd + 2016ac - 2017ad - 2017bc - 2016bd = 0$$

I am hopeless at this point, how do you even factorise this?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you got a source for this question? Looks impossible to me.

Comment: No I have not, is it impossible? Can you explain why so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let
$$t=\frac{(a-b)(c-d)}{(b-c)(d-a)}=\frac{ac+bd-ad-bc}{ac+bd-ab-cd}$$
then
$$t-1=\frac{ab+cd-ad-bc}{ac+bd-ab-cd}=\frac{(a-c)(b-d)}{(b-c)(d-a)}$$
so
$$\frac{(a-c)(b-d)}{(a-b)(c-d)}=\frac{t-1}{t}.$$

Comment: Oh I get it , how do you come with such an idea ?

Comment: @Anonymous These are "cross-ratios".

Comment: Ok I see , thanks for the answer .

Answer (score 1):

Quite similar approach:

$$\frac{2016}{2017}=1-\frac{1}{2017}$$

$$\frac{(a-b)(c-d)}{(b-c)(d-a)}=1-\frac{1}{(b-c)(d-a)}$$

After reducing we get:

$$(a-c)(b-d)=-1=-\frac{(a-b)(c-d)}{(a-b)(c-d)}$$

Or:

$$\frac{(a-c)(b-d)}{(a-b)(c-d)}=\frac{-1}{(a-b)(c-d)}=-\frac{1}{2016}$$